# What gets cached in second level cache?

Tags: java, hibernate

From the Hibernate documentation (emphasis mine):

> By default, **entities are not part of the second level cache** and we recommend you to stick to this setting. However, you can override this by setting the shared-cache-mode element in your persistence.xml file or by using the javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode property in your configuration.

What gets cached in the second-level cache?

Comment: you got the answer there in the question ;)

Comment: No I didn't. "By default, entities are not part of the second level cache and we recommend you to stick to this setting." Because from the statement it is not clear does it mean that "by default caching is not enabled and you have to enable it to take advantage of this cache just like query cache is not enabled because it doesn't benefit most queries" or "by default some thing else other than the entities are cached". The language of the hibernate documentation is always confusing as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You got first level cache and second level cache.
First level cache remains on the transaction that's why you have to call flush in order to be consistent among transactions using the same row.
Second level cache however is shared between transactions.

Same objects are cached the difference is whether they are shared between sessions or not.

Answer (score 0):

By default the second cache is disabled.

1. If you try to load an entiry, hibernate try to find it in the first level cash. If there is no cached entity in first level cache, then second level cache is looked up for cached entity.
2. If second level cache has cached entity, it is returned as result of load method. But, before returning the entity, it is stored in first level cache also so that next invocation to load method for entity will return the entity from first level cache itself, and there will not be need to go to second level cache again.

If you want use the second level cache, try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "for_second_cache")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class ObjectForSecondCache{
    private Set<Document> documents;
}
```

Also, you should know that there are many different providers for the second level cache.

Comment: Second level cache isn't restricted to just load(). Works the same even with get().

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has 2 caching mechanisms.

**1. First level cache:**

**It is enabled by default** and cannot be disabled. It applies to caching provided within a session, i.e. when a session has been opened and database calls are performed.

For example, if you have invoke `session.get(<entity>, <id>)` for a particular id and before closing the session, if you invoke it again with the same id, then Hibernate just makes one call to the database, stores in the first level cache; and for the second, it just gets it from the cache.

You can see the benefit when there is a `session.save()` performed and if some properties are updated (within the session), then it triggers an update query to reflect the changes made, without the need to invoke `session.update()`.

**2. Second level cache:**

***a. Caching entities:***

**This is disabled by default and is applicable across sessions**. It is usually meant for maintaining cache across different sessions within a session factory but can also be scaled to multiple clusters.

Once the second level cache has been enabled, you will also need to specify the *classes/entities which are to be considered for caching*. This ensures that Hibernate looks at the second level cache (and the first level cache) before making a call to the database and updates the cache accordingly, so that further requests can be served/retrieved from the cache itself.

For example,

```
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
```

and

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class EntityToBeCached ...
```

***b. Caching queries:***

Likewise, query cache needs to be enabled explicitly to *make the queries cacheable*. This holds good only when second level cache has been enabled.
In this case, you need to mark the query/queries cacheable by using `query.setCacheable(true)` on the query being executed and also further queries which you need to look up in the cache before a call to DB.

This is required along with enabling second level cache.

```
<property name="cache.query_cache">true</property>
```

The description has been quite long but I hope you got the idea :)